# SendKeys not punching the Whole String, instead punching only few letters of the string in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Code in which i am logging in the web page by entering Login ID and Password, but while i am using the sendKeys method for entering the UserName and Password, the method is only punching few selective letters from the whole user name.
This code was working fine, but now i am getting this error everytime i am executing my script. i have tried wait statements, clicking on the elements but nothing worked. The Help will be appriciated a lot. k
kindly find the Code for the same

```js
driver.get(Constants.web_address);
WebElement HRTabBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > my-app > login > div > div.inner-container > div > div.col-xs-offset-1.col-xs-3.loginBox > div > center:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > span > span"));
HRTabBtn.click();
WebElement userID = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mce-USERID"));
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mce-PASSWORD"));
WebElement LoginBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form > div:nth-child(7) > div > center > button"));
userID.clear();
userID.sendKeys(Constants.user_id);
pwd.clear();
pwd.sendKeys(Constants.password);
LoginBtn.click();
```

The HTML Code For the Login Page:

```html
<div _ngcontent-nee-8="" class="row">
  <div _ngcontent-nee-8="" class="col-xs-6">
    <input _ngcontent-nee-8="" id="mce-USERID" name="user_id" ngcontrol="userID" placeholder="UserID" required="required" type="text" value="" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-nee-8="" class="col-xs-6">
    <input _ngcontent-nee-8="" id="mce-PASSWORD" name="password" ngcontrol="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" type="password" value="" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">
  </div>
</div>

<div _ngcontent-nee-8="" class="row">
  <div _ngcontent-nee-8="" class="col-xs-12">
    <center _ngcontent-nee-8=""><button _ngcontent-nee-8="" class="button btn btn-success">SIGN IN</button></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried sending one key at a time

Comment: are you facing the issues all the time or some time? If you are getting this all the time, try updating the driver and browser

Comment: Is this specific in IE browser or across all browsers? Try updating your webdriver version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem through sending one character at a time. which i am doing through the below method

```js
public static void sendChar(WebElement element, String value) {
  element.clear();

  for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
    char c = value.charAt(i);
    String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
    element.sendKeys(s);
  }
}
```

Use This Method to Enter the String in the Edit Boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. I have used actions class here.

```
driver.get(Constants.web_address);
WebElement HRTabBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > my-app > login > div > div.inner-container > div > div.col-xs-offset-1.col-xs-3.loginBox > div > center:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > span > span"));
HRTabBtn.click();
WebElement userID = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mce-USERID"));
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mce-PASSWORD"));
WebElement LoginBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form > div:nth-child(7) > div > center > button"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
userID.clear();
//userID.sendKeys(Constants.user_id);
actions.sendKeys(userID, Constants.user_id).perform();
pwd.clear();
//pwd.sendKeys(Constants.password);
actions.sendKeys(pwd,Constants.password);
LoginBtn.click();
```